# PHP GD Set image behind transparent image

Tags: php, image, transparent, php-gd

I need to put one image behind another image which is transparent. Another way of explaining this is changing the priority of what is shown first. Perhaps a layer? My code puts background (bg.png) on top/in front of the transparent image (sig.png):

```
header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );

$im = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( 'public/sig.png' ) );

imagealphablending( $im, true );

imagesavealpha( $im, true );

$temp = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( 'public/bg.png' ) );

imagecopy( $im, $temp, 34, 88, 0, 0, 850, 300 );

imagepng( $im );

imagedestroy( $im );
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching the first two parameters in your call to `imagecopy` will fix the draw order (you might need to update the other parameters too):

```
imagecopy($temp, $im, 34, 88, 0, 0, 850, 300);
imagepng($temp);
```

As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php), `imagecopy` can be used to:

> Copy a part of `src_im` onto `dst_im`...

`src_im` is the *second* parameter, `dst_im` is the *first* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I created my custom image with transparent background as base and then merged two other images both background and main content together.

Thank you.